# Ruby on Rails - Keep selected images in form after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave, filefield

I use `simple_form` for handling forms & `CarrierWave gem` for handling **image upload** in my application.

Sometimes when submitting the form, `CarrierWave` gives some errors regarding images, such as: *(Files looks like to be another format etc)*.

After error, all my selected images inside `file_field :image` fields gets empty/null and I have to select them one by one again.

*I usually have 30+ nested forms and 30+ image uploads and I use nested_forms to add each image*

How can I prevent the form to empty/null `file_field :image` fields if form has some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add a hidden field called image_cache

```
<`%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>`
```

You can find this information on the [Carrierwave Github page](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#making-uploads-work-across-form-redisplays).

Comment: sorry typo:  <%= f.hidden_field :image_cache %>